# Is it ok to use ScriptManager without UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms

There is a custom web server control I my WebForms app.
In OnPreRender of this control Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript is used to register script that modifies appearance of control's content.
I use UpdatePanel to add those controls dinamically by clicking the button.
Considering that control is being created during partial-page update(Ajax) call of RegisterStartupScript doesn't work.
I notices that if use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript script is being added successfully even in case control is on page without UpdatePanel but with ScriptManager.

Won't it have any drawbacks if I use ScriptManager in case of usual postbacks, without UpdatePanel?

Comment: What do you mean? In what way I could use it without a ScriptManager?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. I thought you asked if you can use an UpdatePanel without a script manager, but you're asking the reverse. Yes, you can do what you've asked. UpdatePanel depends on ScriptManager, not the other way around.

Comment: That's ok. I just found such info here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408(v=vs.100).aspx). "If you want to register a startup script that does not pertain to partial-page updates, and if you want to register the script only one time during initial page rendering, use the RegisterStartupScript method of the ClientScriptManager class.". Does it mean that it is forbidden to use ScriptManager not for partial-page updates?

Comment: You're reading too much into it. If it says you can't, then you can't. If it doesn't say you can't, then don't assume you can't. Just try it out and see if it works.